# how to uncomment/comment python file using NERD Comment

Tags: python, vim, nerdcommenter

the example given in the official doc is C
and I change into python

```
" Add spaces after comment delimiters by default
let g:NERDSpaceDelims = 1

" Use compact syntax for prettified multi-line comments
let g:NERDCompactSexyComs = 1

" Align line-wise comment delimiters flush left instead of following code indentation
let g:NERDDefaultAlign = 'left'

" Add your own custom formats or override the defaults
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = { 'python': { 'left': '#' } } <==

" Allow commenting and inverting empty lines (useful when commenting a region)
let g:NERDCommentEmptyLines = 1

" Enable trimming of trailing whitespace when uncommenting
let g:NERDTrimTrailingWhitespace = 1

"
```

but it didn't work when I hit `<leader>cc` and also don't work by hitting `<leader>cu`?

besides, how to change the default mapping key for this plugin like change `<leader>cc` to `<leader>c` to comment ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to teach NERDCommenter about Python; it already knows that the comment prefix is `#` (and if it didn't, it falls back to Vim's `'commentstring'` option, which also knows about Python).

If that does not work, it looks as if your plugin installation is broken.

---

The remapping is described under `:help NERDComMappings`. That remapping would be:

```
map <Leader>c <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
```

As the other NERDCommenter mappings start with `<Leader>c`, I would advise against this. As Vim cannot tell whether the mapping is done or you'll keep typing, there will be a delay until the mapping applies. Only way to get rid of that is remapping / deleting all other NERDCommenter mappings. Because of the timeout, the default `<Leader>cc` is actually faster to execute than what you have in mind.